# Does SVG text have a minimal size?

Tags: html, svg, text

It seems I'm hitting a lower limit on font-size or text in SVG. I can't seem to find anything about it in the docs, though.

I have a huge div, that contains a huge SVG part of which is filling the viewport completely. As a result my font-size can be less than 0.0105pt. At which point the text just disappears!

See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wc95t4dk/30/

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:-100000px; left: -100000px; width: 200000px; height:200000px">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
        <text x="50.1" y="50.1" font-size="0.1pt" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.01" fill="red">My text</text>
        <text x="50.15" y="50.15" font-size="0.011pt" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.001" fill="green">My text2</text>
        <text x="50.25" y="50.15" font-size="0.01pt" stroke="blue" stroke-width="0.001" fill="blue">My text2</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

The red and green text displays fine but the blue one doesn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27165622/227507
 it is caused by implementation detail where only 8 bits of precision (1/256) are reserved for decimal digits

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about all browsers, but neither Chrome nor Firefox will render text whose font size is less than 0.5 screen pixels.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/vsxgy3fq/5/

However things get more complicated when there are SVG `viewBox` transforms (and other transforms) involved.  I know that browsers have (or had) bugs related to this size check.