# CSS different output in mozilla firefox and internet explorer

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, mozilla

I'm practicing css and I came across this problem. I'm using an svg as a background. I get the result that I want when I try to run it in Opera and Google Chrome, like this:
[image]

But when I try to run it in mozilla, it appears like this, there are a few spaces in the top and bottom:
[image]

And also, in Internet Explorer, the svg appeared a lot more out of place, like this:
[image]

I've tried using css reset, but nothing happened.

Here is my svg code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 22.58">
<defs><style>.cls-1{fill:url(#linear-gradient);}</style><linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="15.6" y1="9.41" x2="10.68" y2="22.94" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" stop-color="#65ffb7"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#47f2d0"/></linearGradient></defs>
<title>landing bg</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
<polygon class="cls-1" points="10.54 0 0 16.03 9.31 22.58 24 22.58 24 0 10.54 0"/></g></g></svg>
```

CSS Code

```
body
{
    background-color: white;

}

.frame1
{
    background: #000000 url('../images/landing_bg.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    height: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 900px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main page/main.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main page/reset.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "frame1">

    </div>
</body>
```

Am I missing something or is there something that I should remove in order to get my desired result(see first picture) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your viewbox of the svg is the problem.

Try e.g.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
```

To be honest, I am not able to provide any information to explain this behaviour. But I've found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161079/svg-viewbox-resolution-limits), maybe it's related to the reason.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, try switching the positions of your `main.css` and `reset.css` links in the head. Stylesheets are loaded in the sequence they are linked and this may be why your reset is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I got my desired result on mozilla when I changed the svg viewBox. But for Internet Explorer, nothing happened when I changed the svg viewBox. Maybe I'll try adding a stylesheet that is specifically for Internet Explorer.

P.S.
Sorry for the late response, I got sick :/ but I am well now. Thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't had a look at IE, just FF. In IE it looks like the stylesheets for .frame1 might be the problem in this combination. For me it looks like in FF the scale up with width 100% works different as in IE. I tried removing the width:100% and the impact is "massive" in IE, but not in FF.  Maybe you want to play around a bit to see the impact.